Getting Deadlock in Azure SQL Server and Victim query in Microsoft Internal Query

I am getting Deadlock in Azure SQL Server
There is only 1 Victim query which "Looks like" Microsoft Internal query.



The other Query is Alter Column Statement
ALTER TABLE [SomeSchemaName].[SomeTableName] ALTER COLUMN [SomeColumnName] nvarchar NULL

Azure SQL has Auto tunning enabled , hence it would keep on creating and dropping indexes.

Deadlock graph looks like below




Hi Sagar, it is more useful to post text instead of images.  That way, others can copy and search for it or try it out themselves.
